# Replace card view dynamically

Tags: java, android, list, listview, replace

I am new to android so unable to get the solution for this. I am trying to replace my card layout based on object type. I have tried to do it by if else but unable to get the result. Only bigcircle layout is displayed every time.

I want to display small and big circle. If object type is 1 small circle should be displayed in card and if object type is 2 big circle should be displayed. so for that I thought of replacing card layout. So I have created two adapter for two cards and tried to display based on type. What am I missing?

**Expense class**

```
public class Expense {

String amount;
String expense;
public int expenseType;

Expense(){}
Expense(String amount,String expense,int expenseType)
{
    this.amount=amount;
    this.expense=expense;
    this.expenseType=expenseType;
}

public void setExpenseType(int expenseType)
{
    this.expenseType=expenseType;
}
public int getExpenseType()
{
    return expenseType;
}
```

**cardlayout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
android:background="@android:color/white">
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/txtAmount"
            android:text="text1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:background="@drawable/line" />

            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/small"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"/>


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:background="@drawable/line" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtexpense"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Small circle Adapter**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

List<Expense> items;


ItemAdapter(List<Expense> items){

    this.items = items;

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
    itemViewHolder.amount.setText(items.get(i).amount);
    itemViewHolder.expense.setText(items.get(i).expense);

}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {



    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, viewGroup, false);

    return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        CardView cv1;
        TextView amount;
        TextView expense;
        ImageView small;


        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            amount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
            expense = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtexpense);
            small = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.small);

        }
    }
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
 }
}
```

**Big circle layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:measureWithLargestChild="false">
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/txtAmount"
            android:text="text1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:background="@drawable/line" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/big"
                android:background="@drawable/circle1" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:background="@drawable/line" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtexpense"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Big circle Adapter**

```
public class bigCircleAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<bigCircleAdapter.ItemViewHolder>{

    List<Expense> items;


   bigCircleAdapter(List<Expense> items){

        this.items = items;

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
        itemViewHolder.amount.setText(items.get(i).amount);
        itemViewHolder.expense.setText(items.get(i).expense);

    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {



        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.bigcircle, viewGroup, false);

        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        CardView cv1;
        TextView amount;
        TextView expense;
        ImageView small;



        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv1 = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view1);
            amount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
            expense= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtexpense);
            small = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.big);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

I am displaying the list in fragment.

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {
ArrayList<Expense> items=new ArrayList<Expense>();

RecyclerView recyclerView;
public ItemFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    Expense e=new Expense();

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_fab);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    initializeDataType1();
    int type= e.getExpenseType();

    if(type==2)
    {

        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else
    {

        bigCircleAdapter ad = new bigCircleAdapter(items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ad);
    }


    return view;

}

private void initializeDataType1() {

    items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new Expense("1000", "2000", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("2000", "5000", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("3000", "400", 2));
    items.add(new Expense("1000", "4000", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("3000", "3000", 2));
    items.add(new Expense("2000", "100", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("2000", "3333", 2));
    items.add(new Expense("3000", "shopping", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("1000", "food", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("1000", "food", 2));
    items.add(new Expense("2000", "drink", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("3000", "shopping", 2));
    items.add(new Expense("2000", "3333", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("3000", "shopping", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("1000", "food", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("1000", "food", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("2000", "drink", 1));
    items.add(new Expense("3000", "shopping", 1));
}
}
```

I have added dummy data in the list. When type is 1 big circle layout should be displayed and records of type 1 should be displayed respectively. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You know you could use a single adapter and just change the underlying layout according to when you add an item to the List, by putting some simpler identifier/flag?

Comment: Yes I have solved the problem by same way....Thank u..